# Resources for learning about philosophy of mind and consciousness

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

I would like to devote a significant amount of time over the next year learning about philosophy of mind with a specific focus on topics related to phenomenal consciousness. I have a background primarily in engineering.

I would prefer to begin with popular work produced for the general public, which might help put significant problems and work on the subject into historical context, and progress towards more rigorous material over time. Where might you suggest I begin?

Comment: There are some suggestions under Philosophy of Consciousness Book Recommendation http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37985/philosophy-of-consciousness-book-recommendation/37987#37987

Comment: Start here: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/ ... as you learn the basic, you'll know what to look for

Comment: I'd just be careful not to confuse a study of philosophy of mind with a study of consciousness. If you read the recommended literature you'll soon see that these are not at all the same thing. I don't know a good introduction to phil. of mind and can only suggest diving straight into the Journal of Consciousness Studies. If you were local I'd donate all my old copies since they don't age  Or, perhaps William James would be a good way in. He doesn't age either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comprehensive understanding of consciousness will likely require theories of many types.

One might usefully and without contradiction accept a diversity of models that each in their own way aim respectively to explain **the physical, neural, cognitive, functional, representational and higher-order aspects of consciousness.**

There is unlikely to be any single theoretical perspective that suffices for explaining all the features of consciousness that we wish to understand.

Thus **a synthetic and pluralistic** approach may provide the best road to ...

some internet resources-

**Journal of Consciousness Studies**

How does the mind relate to the brain?
Can computers ever be conscious?
What do we mean by subjectivity and the self?
These questions are being keenly debated in fields as diverse as cognitive science, neurophysiology and philosophy. JCS is a peer-reviewed journal which examines these issues in plain English.

> http://www.imprint.co.uk/product/jcs/

**Association for the Scientific Study of Consciousness.**

The ASSC is an academic society that promotes rigorous research and coordinates annual conferences directed toward understanding the nature, function, and underlying mechanisms of consciousness. The ASSC includes members working in the fields of cognitive science, medicine, neuroscience, philosophy, and other relevant disciplines in the sciences and humanities.

> http://theassc.org/about-us/

**Center for Consciousness Studies (University of Arizona/Tucson).**

> http://consciousness.arizona.edu/

The Science of Consciousness
Conference - TUCSON - 2018
NEW - 2018 Plenary Session - Videos

> https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/#Oth