# Where to start to be savvy about the current literature on consciousness?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

I imagine that there are probably only a few major schools of thought, though this may be a misjudgment on my part.

I am very familiar with Daniel Dennett's work, Chalmers, Hoffman's (though I'm not sure if I consider him a serious player).

I want to be able to tackle this issue from all angles, but it's difficult to know where they are.

Comment: It depends how deep you want to go. Dennett is all over YouTube giving arguments in broad brush strokes. Look up Penrose (not the main guy for this but the only one I can remember) and 'microtubules'. I think the state of play is the same as it ever was. The empiricists/monists say consciousness arises from the operation of the brain, and must therefore explain free will. The idealists/dualists have to explain what consciousness is made of and why we can't observe that 'stuff' through experiment.

Comment: If you mean the literature of academic consciousness studies then I'd highly recommend a subscription to the Journal of Consciousness Studies. If you mean something more broad than this to include 'empirical' research then I'd recommend Sri Krishna Prem's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita or perhaps Alan Watts' book 'This Is It'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are book recommendations on Philosophy of Consciousness by contemporary authors?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37985/what-are-book-recommendations-on-philosophy-of-consciousness-by-contemporary-aut)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are plainly familiar with major players. For a conspectus you might try :

Susan Blackmore, Consciousness A Very Short Introduction, ISBN 10: 0198794738 / ISBN 13: 9780198794738
Published by OXFORD UNIVERSITY PRESS, 2018.

To go deeper, as you obviously will want to :

Uriah Kriegel, The Varieties of Consciousness, ISBN 10: 0190945982 / ISBN 13: 9780190945985
Published by Oxford University Press Inc, United States, 2019.

Andrea Diem-Lane, David Lane, The Library of Consciousness: Exploring Evolutionary Epistemology, ISBN 10: 1565436962 / ISBN 13: 9781565436961
Published by Mount San Antonio College/Philosophy Group, United States, 2017.

Ted Honderich, Actual Consciousness, ISBN 10: 0198776918 / ISBN 13: 9780198776918
Published by Oxford University Press, United Kingdom, 2016.