# What is the philosophical notion of "intelligibility"?

Tags: epistemology, semantics

Can you please point me to philosophical discussions of *intelligibility* or of what counts as *intelligible*? — or to an accepted intelligible view of *intelligibility*, if there is such a thing (pun intended).

I was surprised that I have failed to find anything satisfying with Google. See for example the SEP article on [*The Principle of Sufficient Reason*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sufficient-reason/). This is how it opens:

> The Principle of Sufficient Reason is a powerful and controversial philosophical principle stipulating that everything must have a reason, cause, or ground. This simple demand for thoroughgoing **intelligibility** yields some of the boldest and most challenging theses in the history of philosophy.

However, while the article employs the term *intelligibility* several times, I have found no discussion of what *intelligibility* means in SEP.

Most dictionaries define *intelligible* roughly as *able to be understood*, but as we all know we poorly understand what it means to *understand*.

I have been quietly using *intelligibility* in the sense given by Chomsky in [*On Nature and Language*](https://tinyurl.com/y9mz39yh):

> The galilean model of intelligibility has a corollary: when mechanism fails, understanding fails.

That is, what cannot be understood mechanically, cannot be considered intelligible. For example, Newton's theory of gravity is an intelligible theory (it is a collection of simple formulas that a computer can work through), but (Newtonian) action at a distance which underlies the phenomena of gravity is itself unintelligible, as pointed out by [David Hume](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hume-newton/#Ske):

> While Newton seemed to draw off the veil from some of the mysteries of nature, he shewed at the same time the imperfections of the mechanical philosophy; and thereby restored her ultimate secrets to that obscurity, in which they ever did and ever will remain.

But provoked by a recent discussion I am looking for philosophical discussions of *intelligibility*. Any pointers and insights would be welcome (but please no home-made half-baked out of the sleeve ideas).

Comment: Good historical reference: Petr Dear, [The Intelligibility of Nature: How Science Makes Sense of the World](https://books.google.it/books?id=W1GAG3vJHpgC&printsec=frontcover). Intelligible=understandable; no way to define all.

Comment: The point of Chomsky's statement is that the "criteria" for understanding change in time, with the development of science and philosophy.

Comment: Maybe useful:  von Wright, [Explanation and Understanding](https://books.google.it/books?id=CrFlAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, It seems to me that while they may be closely related, nevertheless _understanding_ and _intelligibility_ are not generally considered to be identical. Also I disagree that Chomsky's point is that criteria for scientific understanding merely changed over time. I believe that his point in that and other papers is that reality is ultimately mysterious or unintelligible, or beyond human capacity to reason, or fully comprehend. Chomsky is a mysterian.

Comment: However, the reference to Peter Dear is good. Could be made into an answer.

Comment: Here is an interesting article:  http://jcrt.org/religioustheory/2017/05/09/the-one-is-not-on-the-fate-of-unity-in-post-metaphysical-philosophy-jussi-backman/

Comment: @Gordon, interesting in what way?

Comment: "The problem of the One and the Many considered in its full range, up to the very meeting of pure Unity (pure Intelligibility) and pure Multiplicity (pure Materiality), is from the start presented to us as "solved"in a vital synthesis which is both subjective and objective." Culminate in the Aristotelianism of St. Thomas. Began to break up with Duns Scotus and Ockham. Resulted in "intuitive and analytical theory of the concept" (a burden) and ultimately two clearly divergent systems, a) rationalistic dogmatism and b) phenomenalistic empiricism." Joseph Marechal.

Comment: Nir, I am studying this myself right now so I am not an expert on this subject. I am reading an excellent book: A Marechal Reader, Herder and Herder (1970) in an attempt to fill the gaps in my own philosophical education.

Comment: So anyway I am studying Joseph Marechal not for his Transcendental Thomism, but for his brilliant exposition of the history of philosophy and central problems. In French, multi volume: https://archive.org/details/lepointdedpartde01marc In English the Herder and Herder Marechal Reader (1970).

Answer (score 4):

The original meaning of "intelligible" was of that apprehended by the intellect as opposed to the senses, for example Plato (in Latin translations) talks about intelligibles (forms) vs sensibles (things), see Karl's [Plato’s Two World Theory](https://cameronscottkarl.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/the-two-worlds-plato%E2%80%99s-two-world-theory-from-the-gorgias-to-the-republic), and Aristotle's use is similar.

In more recent philosophy there are two somewhat different meanings of "intelligible", both distinct from the traditional one (although inspired by it). For example, [Creighton in The Form of Philosophical Intelligibility](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2939616) writes:

> "*We habitually assign to philosophy the task of "explaining" the world, or of rendering experience "intelligible"...  It would seem necessary to understand as clearly and definitely as possible what type of explanation philosophy may properly be expected to furnish before any discussion is in order regarding its competency to fulfill its task, or concerning the relative value and pertinency of various systems.*"

This reading links intelligibility to explanation, and on explanation there is of course also a long philosophical tradition. [Aristotle's four causes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-causality/#FouCau) were originally construed as four ways to answer "why" questions, i.e. they are more properly translated as reasons or explanations. Only one of them, the efficient cause under which mechanistic explanations fall, was retained by modern science as fundamental, and eventually "cause" came to be identified with what Aristotle called "efficient cause", with additional twist that such causes are also assumed to be governed by (often deterministic) laws. Modern philosophical naturalism largely adopted this outlook, but with a revision. Even in modern physics mechanistic explanations are insufficient, Chomsky's view was abandoned there along with classical mechanics, and replaced with a more general paradigm of (efficiently) causal explanation. On the other hand, this is perhaps why many people still see quantum physics as not sufficiently intelligible.

Evolutionary explanations in biology are often teleological rather than causal (physiological traits are explained by being advantageous in species' environment, for example), corresponding to Aristotle's final causes, but such explanations are usually seen as derivative from efficient ones via the mechanisms of mutation and natural selection. The fundamental priority of causal explanations depends, however, on the success of the reductionist/physicalist programme, which in philosophy of mind is controversial, see [Is there a causal influence of the mental on the physical?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/32430/9148) Modern philosophical theories of scientific explanation are well-covered by both [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-explanation) and [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/explanat). The [Friedman-Kitcher unificationist theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-explanation/#UniAccExp) is perhaps the most popular, in Kitcher's summary:

> "*Science advances our understanding of nature by showing us how to derive descriptions of many phenomena, using the same pattern of derivation again and again, and in demonstrating this, it teaches us how to reduce the number of facts we have to accept as ultimate.*"

A somewhat different meaning of "intelligibility" puts emphasis not on  explanation but on meaningfulness (the two are obviously closely related), "intelligible" is that which meets the conditions of the possibility of being meaningful. Traditionally, such conditions would include logical laws, like identity and non-contradiction, famously challenged by Hegel, and on some accounts even the principle of sufficient reason, although its inclusion is rare today. The prominence of this view can be traced to Kant's "conditions of the possibility" of experience or knowledge, and his employment of these notions in [transcendental arguments](http://www.iep.utm.edu/trans-ar).

Aside from the positive use, where such conditions help analyze the structure of our cognitive faculties, our "intellect", Kant effectively coined a new type of philosophical argumentation, where a view is argued to be not even false, but worse, unintelligible, because its notions violate some conditions of meaningfulness. For instance, according to Kant, the notions of traditional metaphysics are unintelligible because they attempt to apply categories of experience beyond any possible experience, to things in themselves. Such approach was since used by many prominent philosophers whose positions are very far from Kant's. For example, Wittgenstein argued against private sensations and languages because such things have no criterion of correctness required for their intelligibility, see [Did Wittgenstein consider the possibility of a private language with public content?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/34157/9148) Similarly, [Putnam in Realism and Reason](https://www.princeton.edu/~hhalvors/teaching/phi520_f2012/putnam1977.pdf) criticized (metaphysical) realism positing "mind-independent" reality expressed in mind's concepts that "correspond" to it as unintelligible:

> "*But it is unintelligible, from my point of view, how the sort of relation the metaphysical realist envisages as holding between a sign and its object can be singled out either by holding up the sign itself [Cow], – or by holding up yet another sign, thus [Refers] – or perhaps – [Causes]... One of the puzzling things about the metaphysical realist picture is that it  makes it unintelligible how there can be a priori truths, even contextual ones, even as a (possibly unreachable) limit.*"

Comment: What is "Chomsky's view" that "was abandoned there along with classical mechanics" ?

Comment: Why do you say that "many people still see quantum physics as not sufficiently intelligible"? the physics is perfectly intelligible (some say even simple). It is the underlying reality that quantum physics describes that is ultimately unintelligible — for example its non-locality.

Comment: In _Philosophical Investigations_ Wittgenstein does not seem to use the term _intelligibility_ in its problematic sense. He uses it twice in the private language comments, and both uses seem unproblematic, or idiomatic — a language being intelligible by a listener or not — see comments 207 and 261 there.

Comment: Putnam is using the term _intelligible_ in several places in his paper but he never explains what he means by that.

Comment: There is a nice paraphrase in Creighton's paper of "Lord Kelvin that he could understand a theory only when he was able to represent it in a drawing", but otherwise I find his paper rather obscure: "But philosophy in its own domain has no concern with the bare form of existence. To achieve the form of intelligibility at which it aims it is indeed necessary that the mind shall understand the truth that is contained in this abstract standpoint, but it has also to free itself from the domination of existential imagery in order to rise to freedom and universality" — good luck making sense of that.

Comment: @nir - He seems to be saying that for an intelligible metaphysics we have to see beyond the 'domination of existential imagery', by which I presume he means we must look beyond form and even the distinction between existence and non-existence. This is a mainstream idea outside the Academy. But yes, it does take some getting used to.  . . .

Comment: @PeterJ, to look beyond "the distinction between existence and non-existence" ? where in his paper does he talk of such a thing? in the quote he appears to be talking of a truth contained in some abstract standpoint, not of a truth beyond concepts.

Comment: @nir Chomsky's view is quoted in your post. *I* do not say whether QM is or is not intelligible, people say what they say. Wittgenstein works with post-Kantian idea of meaningfulness, whether he uses the word is moot. You asked what philosophers "mean", it is not surprising that what they "mean" may seem obscure or presuppose things you disagree with. This is not a kind of practical word that people have a consensus on, but "intelligible" as explained or meaningful are the most typical uses. Since explanation and meaning are analyzed ad nauseum there is no need to repeat it for intelligibility

Comment: @Conifold, in that case I do not understand what you mean by "Even in modern physics mechanistic explanations are insufficient, Chomsky's view was abandoned there along with classical mechanics, and replaced with a more general paradigm of (efficiently) causal explanation." Chomsky's view is this:

Comment: "Instead of trying to show that the world is intelligible to us, we recognized that it’s not intelligible to us. But we just say, ‘Well, you know, unfortunately that’s the way it works. I can’t understand it but that’s the way it works.’ And then the aim of science is reduced from trying to show that the world is intelligible to us, which it is not, to trying to show that there are theories of the world which are intelligible to us. That’s what science is: It’s the study of intelligible theories which give an explanation of some aspect of reality."

Comment: As far as I can tell it is perfectly inline with some statements by modern physicists like Feynman: "I think I can safely say that nobody understands quantum mechanics.", and Bohr: "There is no quantum world. There is only an abstract quantum physical description. It is wrong to think that the task of physics is to find out how nature is. Physics concerns what we can say about nature."

Comment: @nir Chomsky's quote is "when mechanism fails, understanding fails", which is indeed Galileo-Newton's view. Well, mechanism fails already in classical electrodynamics, as Einstein's abolition of mechanical ether symbolized. We can try to revive it, or to inject Bohmian particles into QM to make it feel more comforting, or we can move on and try to make intelligible mathematical structures that are not rooted in mechanics. For me it was easier to understand electrodynamics without Maxwell's rotating wheels, and QM without Bohm's insertions, but I'll admit they can be helpful in some contexts

Comment: @Conifold, you are missing the point and misreading Chomsky. Mechanism fails already in Newtonian mechanics. Both Newton and Chomsky are/were well aware of it. This is why Chomsky and Hume say nature is unintelligible. Additionally there was never a problem of unintelligiblity with the physics, the theories, or mathematics. they are always intelligible. it is reality that is not.  this is the point of the quotes by Feynman Bohr and Chomsky above. Feynman does not complain that no one understands QM theory (he perfectly understood it), but that no one understands the underlying reality.

Comment: @nir There can certainly be problems with intelligibility of physical and mathematical theories (GR, QFT are current examples). As for reality, applying "intelligible" to it seems to be treating it as a theory of itself.

Comment: @Conifold, I believe we should distinguish between two senses of (un)intelligibility. In the first sense one may say GR is unintelligible to indicate that GR is difficult to comprehend to someone lacking proper mathematical background. The other sense is to indicate that something is impossible to comprehend in principle — this second sense is how Hume views Newtonian action at a distance, and why Feynman famously said of nature "Nobody knows how it can be like that". The first sense maybe applied to a theory; the second sense to reality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66907/discussion-between-conifold-and-nir).